# Can we access podcast in our iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, audio, podcast

I have my iPhone application, i want to call podcast application in iTunes in my application. can anyone please tell me if it is feasible, or any other solution for that ?

Comment: Please be more precise. Exactly what level of access do you need? Do you need to access podcasts stored in the iPod library or do you wan't to control the podcast playing features of iPod app itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant accessing podcasts as iPod content, you can use the MediaPlayback framework to have the user select the podcast then open it as an AVAsset as normal.